# Error when installing Grooveshark Remote Control Firefox extension

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions

When I attempt to install [Grooveshark Remote Control](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/grooveshark-remote-control/) 0.3.1 by clicking on the "Add to Firefox" button on the page below, I receive this error:

> Grooveshark Remote Control could not be installed because Firefox cannot modify the needed file.

I am using XP Home SP 3 and Firefox 4.0.1.

Any way to get this extension installed and working correctly?

Comment: Are you local admin? Or do you have a restricted account on this machine?

Comment: I am the only user of the machine, so should not have any restricted access.  I don't have problems installing Firefox extensions otherwise.

Comment: I've tried the new version - 0.3.2 with Firefox 5 also, but still get the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with XP.  It is discussed here:

https://github.com/peregrinogris/Grooveshark-Remote-Control/issues/18
https://github.com/peregrinogris/Grooveshark-Remote-Control/issues/33